# direct image of a vector bundle in the setup of smooth manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Let $X\rightarrow Y$ be a morphism of topological spaces. Given a sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ on $X$, we have the notion of a direct image sheaf $f_*\mathcal{F}$ on $Y$. If we are starting with $\mathcal{F}$ being a vector bundle over scheme $(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$, then, we expect (under some reasonable assumptions) $f_*\mathcal{F}$ to be a vector bundle over the scheme $(Y,\mathcal{O}_Y)$.

Is there a description of direct image of vector bundles at the setup of smooth manifolds, not involving the notion of sheaf?